# SSL Certificate for a domain name or IP?

Tags: https

I am a bit confused with all the SSL certificate deal.
Can anyone clarify a few things to me please.

I have a domain registered on Godaddy and ec2 instance running on AWS with an elastic IP. With A record pointing to ec2 instance.

Do I have to only buy 1 SSL cert for my domain name?
Or only for elastic IP?
Or do I need both?

Comment: See also: [Multiple IP addresses for one SSL certificate](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55715/multiple-ip-addresses-for-one-ssl-certificate)

Answer (score 3):

It is not desirable to buy a security certificate for an IP address.   The purpose of  the security certificate is warrant that the secure connection is established from the organization identified by the domain name.  While it might be [possible to get a certificate for an IP address](https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1216536-securing-a-public-ip-address---ssl-certificates) when you can prove you own the IP address, certificate authorities (CAs) do not typically issue signed security certificates for IP addresses.

You need to buy a security certificate for your domain name.   You can then use that certificate on any server regardless of its IP address.